# click does not work even after a element_to_be_clickable

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

When running the below code

```
            next_valid_icd = self.check_next_valid_icd_in_list()
            button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_valid_icd)))


            button.click()
```

The button never get clicked

I am running this on geckodriver python 3.7.2

I tried to put a sleep and it works fine

```
            next_valid_icd = self.check_next_valid_icd_in_list()
            button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.timeout).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, next_valid_icd)))

            time.sleep(2)

            button.click()
```

I would like to make it cleaner and avoid using sleep

Comment: Do a safe check if element is_enabled()

Comment: try with different locator such as css selector or id or class name. for more share your HTML.

Comment: Please post your relevant HTML?

Comment: Sorry I tried, but my company did not allow it for security reasons